# Using @Inject in Spring with appserver not compatible with Java EE 6

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, annotations, code-injection

Can I use  `@Inject` annotation in my Spring  application, when I will deploy my application in Appserver that doesn't support Java EE 6?

`@Inject` is introduced in Java EE6 and it doesn't supported by Java EE 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `@Inject` in components managed by Spring (Spring beans) its functionality is implemented by Spring, therefore you don't need anything else to make it work.

`@Inject` support in JavaEE 6 is about components managed by application server (EJBs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Spring has [a synonymous `@Autowired` annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) that has the same effect. Since it's provided by Spring itself, it should be available on any version of Java that supports annotations.

Comment: yes, I know it. So, it's _impossible_ to use `@Inject` without Java EE 6 compatible  AppServer?

Comment: @MyTitle, since the `javax.inject.Inject` class doesn't exist in Java 5, you're going to need to be running on the Java 6 JRE. The AppServer itself probably doesn't need any special support though.

Answer (score 0):

JSR 330's @Inject annotation can be used in place of Spring's @Autowired in the examples below. @Inject does not have a required property unlike Spring's @Autowire annotation which has a required property to indicate if the value being injected is optional. This behavior is enabled automatically if you have the JSR 330 JAR on the classpath.

spring documentation......

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch03s09.html

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can.  If you are using Spring (>= version 3), Spring will perform its dependency injection base on the @Inject annotations of its beans.

In long, it all depends on what do you mean by "Can be used".  Annotation is nothing but a meta data.  No one stop you from using @Inject to perform a totally irrelevant function, as long as you inspect the annotation and do whatever you want